# What is the difference between bcedit and diskpart for deleting partitions

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, diskpart, bcdedit

I successfully removed grub in two different ways:
First one was to use `rmdir` inside the `EFI` volume after assigning it a letter using `diskpart`, and the second one was using `bcdedit` and deleting the volume using the identifier

What is the difference?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods are complementary and their effect may vary between
BIOS/UEFI versions.

Note: You did not remove a volume - you removed an entry in the boot menu.

The
[bcdedit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/bcdedit)
command did:

```
/delete     Deletes **an element** from a specified entry.
```

This deletes the boot entry but may not remove the Grub folder.
For some firmware, the boot entry may be recreated from the folder
if still present.

For a clean sweep, you should also check if the folder was removed and
remove it yourself.
You did right if you used both methods.